# ASP .NET Nested ListView is not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have following sample code, which uses nested ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="list" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="placeHolder"
        OnItemDataBound="listItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><%#Eval("name") %></p>
        <asp:ListView ID="sublist" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="subPlaceHolder">
            <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("subName") %></ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="subPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

But nested ListView (sublist) is not recognized as a variable in my script code, so I can't access it and provide some databinding. When I add some other object inside main ListView (e.g. DataSource), it is also not recognized.
How can I access nested ListView?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: what is your 'script code'? Do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: No, I mean C# server-side code, which handle OnItemDataBound of the main list. Nested ListView (sublist) is reported as not known in the current context.

Comment: Could you show the OnItemDataBound code you're trying to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls in the `ItemTemplate` will be created multiple times, once for each item in your data source, so the compiler cannot generate a single field to represent them. You'll need to use `FindControl` instead:

```
protected void listItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
   var sublist = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("sublist");
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Within your `OnItemDataBound` event code, you'll have to do this:

```
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
 {
    ListView sublist = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("sublist");
 }
```

In order to find your nested ListView